# Is there any event type for html element in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I had written function which was called when an element change and then I was looking for type for this event.
Everything what I found is jquery type - `JQuery.TypeEventHandler<TElement, null, TElement, TElement, 'change'>` but it not readable for using:

```
    this._element.change((event: JQuery.TypeEventHandler<TElement, null, TElement, TElement, 'change'>) => {...}
```

UPD: I want to get something like this:

```
this._element.change((event: ChangeEvent) => {
let element:JQuery<HTMLElement> = event.currentTarget;
}
```

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Please describe in detail WHAT you are hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but in the browser there is Event interface and some others that implements it e.g. UIEvent.
You could check for some types of event listed in MDN documentation.
Other option might be type property of the event.

### [Event - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

```
const eventEmitter = document.getElementById("foo")!;

eventEmitter.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```